# ValueError: Data overlaps. in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe **df3** that looks like this

with unknown columns length as **AAA_???** can be anything from the dataset

```
           Date    ID  Calendar_Year Month   DayName...  AAA_1E AAA_BMITH  AAA_4.1  AAA_CH
0    2019-09-17  8661           2019   Sep       Sun...     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
1    2019-09-18  8662           2019   Sep       Sun...     1.0       3.0     34.0     1.0
2    2019-09-19  8663           2019   Sep       Sun...     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
3    2019-09-20  8664           2019   Sep       Mon...     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
4    2019-09-20  8664           2019   Sep       Mon...     2.0       4.0     32.0     3.0
5    2019-09-20  8664           2019   Sep       Sat...     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
6    2019-09-20  8664           2019   Sep       Sat...     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
7    2019-09-20  8664           2019   Sep       Sat...     0.0       4.0     30.0     0.0
```

another dataframe **dfMeans** that has the mean of a third dataframe

```
     Month Dayname           ID  ...  AAA_BMITH    AAA_4.1  AAA_CH
0      Jan     Thu  7686.500000  ...   0.000000  28.045455     0.0
1      Jan     Fri  7636.272727  ...   0.000000  28.136364     0.0
2      Jan     Sat  7637.272727  ...   0.000000  27.045455     0.0
3      Jan     Sun  7670.090909  ...   0.000000  27.090909     0.0
4      Jan     Mon  7702.909091  ...   0.000000  27.727273     0.0
5      Jan     Tue  7734.260870  ...   0.000000  27.956522     0.0
```

the dataframes will be joined by **Month** and **Dayname**

I want to replace NaNs in df3 with values from dfMean

using this line

```
df3.update(dfMeans, overwrite=False, errors="raise")
```

but I get this error

> **raise ValueError("Data overlaps.")**
>
> **ValueError: Data overlaps.**

How to update NaNs with values from dfMean and avoid this error?

Edit :

I have put all dataframes in one dataframe **df**

```
     Month Dayname           ID  ...  AAA_BMITH    AAA_4.1  AAA_CH
0      Jan     Thu  7686.500000  ...   0.000000  28.045455     0.0
1      Jan     Fri  7636.272727  ...   0.000000  28.136364     0.0
2      Jan     Sat  7637.272727  ...   0.000000  27.045455     0.0
3      Jan     Sun  7670.090909  ...   0.000000  27.090909     0.0
4      Jan     Mon  7702.909091  ...   0.000000  27.727273     0.0
5      Jan     Tue  7734.260870  ...   0.000000  27.956522     0.0
```

How can I fill NaNs with average based on **Month** and **Dayname**?

Comment: To be sure I understand... do you want to calculate the average in each month and put it in place of `nan` at that month?

Comment: @Valentino yes, except for each Month and Dayname at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

#### Data:

```py
       Date    ID  Calendar_Year Month Dayname  AAA_1E  AAA_BMITH  AAA_4.1  AAA_CH
 2019-09-17  8661           2019   Jan     Sun     NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN
 2019-09-18  8662           2019   Jan     Sun     1.0        3.0     34.0     1.0
 2019-09-19  8663           2019   Jan     Sun     NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN
 2019-09-20  8664           2019   Jan     Mon     NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN
 2019-09-20  8664           2019   Jan     Mon     2.0        4.0     32.0     3.0
 2019-09-20  8664           2019   Jan     Sat     NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN
 2019-09-20  8664           2019   Jan     Sat     NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN
 2019-09-20  8664           2019   Jan     Sat     0.0        4.0     30.0     0.0

df.set_index(['Month', 'Dayname'], inplace=True)
```

[image]

#### df_mean:

```py
Month Dayname           ID  AAA_BMITH    AAA_4.1  AAA_CH
  Jan     Thu  7686.500000        0.0  28.045455     0.0
  Jan     Fri  7636.272727        0.0  28.136364     0.0
  Jan     Sat  7637.272727        0.0  27.045455     0.0
  Jan     Sun  7670.090909        0.0  27.090909     0.0
  Jan     Mon  7702.909091        0.0  27.727273     0.0
  Jan     Tue  7734.260870        0.0  27.956522     0.0

df_mean.set_index(['Month', 'Dayname'], inplace=True)
```

[image]

#### Update `df`:

- This operation is based on matching index values
- It doesn't work with multiple column names at once, you'll have to get the columns of interest and iterate through them
- Note, `AAA_1E` isn't in `df_mean`

```py
for col in df.columns:
    if col in df_mean.columns:
        df[col].fillna(df_mean[col], inplace=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` on `'Month'` and `DayName'` and use `apply` to edit the dataframe.
Use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill the `Nan` values. `fillna` accepts a dictionary as `value` parameter: keys of the dictionary are column names, values are scalars: the scalars are used to substitute the `Nan` in each column. With `loc` you can select the proper value from `dMeans`.
You can create the dictionary with a dict comprehension, using the intersection between columns of `df3` and `dfMeans`.

All this corresponds to the following statement:

```
df3filled = df3.groupby(['Month', 'DayName']).apply(lambda x : x.fillna(
    {col : dfMeans.loc[(dfMeans['Month'] == x.name[0]) & (dfMeans['Dayname'] == x.name[1]), col].iloc[0]
    for col in x.columns.intersection(dfMeans.columns)})).reset_index(drop=True)
```